# Robot Arm Calibration for Schunk 7-DOF Arm

Tags: ros, calibration, robot-calibration, schunk

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am searching for a sophisticated way to calibrate a Schunk (Amtec) arm where some joints are not in zero position (when they should be).
Is there a ROS package for this purpose? Would it be possible/recommended to use the pr2_calibration stack?
Thanks for advice,
David

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9872/robot-arm-calibration-for-schunk-7-dof-arm/) by [David Fischinger](https://answers.ros.org/users/489/david-fischinger/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There has been a similar question with excellent answers [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/102/how-can-i-calibrate-my-real-robot). In summary: Theoretically, you should use the `robot_calibration` and/or `pr2_calibration` stacks, and there seems to be a lot of interest in that, but at the moment these stacks are not really portable. That means you will have to do some serious reconfiguration to get it going on your robot.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The PR2 definitely needs its joints re-zeroed during the calibration process, and the pr2_calibration stack does take care of this.  However, I will reiterate Martin's response in that the stack is not designed to be portable, and further information is available at 
http://answers.ros.org/question/102/how-can-i-calibrate-my-real-robot.

---

Originally posted by [vpradeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/101/vpradeep/) with karma: 760 on 2011-07-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2